# Why does this happen when I put two materials on the same object?

Tags: materials

I have this object

[image]

select the area for another material and click on assign

[image]

when i click on assign, and switch to object mode it happens, and when i go back to edit mode it looks like this too

[image]

But in the viewport shading and when I press F12 it looks like this, normal

[image]

how to take out this big bizarre stretch bug?

Comment: what modifiers do you have enabled?

Comment: none, after i got this result i pressed apply

Comment: Does the material have any displacement maps or anything like that?

Comment: I don't think so, it happens also when I create a new material and just change the base color of the material